# What is this round shaped component called?

Tags: identification, components

[image: I dont know what this component is]

Not sure what this component is. Ive been given some components without any list, so now I am very confused what I can use them for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a DC Motor. It converts electrical energy into mechanical rotation.

More details: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_motor

Comment: They've become quite popular in the last 150 years or so. +1.

Comment: It is also a low-torque, high-speed motor.

Answer (score 1):

The black and red ones are wires. The white one can be a motor, generator or rotation sensor.